# Boost.X3: char_ >> char_ discards the characters and behaves like lit

Tags: c++, boost-spirit-x3

I would like to parse strings with escaping rules similar to that of C.  I want to *keep* the escapes, not decode them and recode afterwards.  So I thought that `*(char_('\\') >> char_ | char_ - '"')` would do what I want, but it does not: it behaves as if I had written `lit('\\')` to discard that guy.

```
#define TEST(Rule) test(input, #Rule, Rule)
int main()
{
  const auto input = std::string{"\\( \\\" \\\\ \\)"};
  TEST(lexeme[*(lit('\\') >> char_ | char_ - '"')]);
  TEST(lexeme[*(char_('\\') >> char_ | char_ - '"')]);
  TEST(lexeme[*char_]);
}
```

gives

```
\( \" \\ \): lexeme[*(lit('\\') >> char_ | char_ - '"')]: ( " \ )
\( \" \\ \): lexeme[*(char_('\\') >> char_ | char_ - '"')]: ( " \ )
\( \" \\ \): lexeme[*char_]: \( \" \\ \)
```

The whole example is available on [Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/56007d3f997b9748).

Comment: This is weird. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3365b20994ce460e - no matter how I try with look ahead it ignores all backslashes.

Answer (score 0):

Your code with the second grammar (`lexeme[*(char_('\\') >> char_ | char_ - '"')]`) is correct (`char_('\\')` should synthesize to attribute of type `char` and return always value `'\\'`).

This has just been confirmed as a bug in Spirit: https://github.com/boostorg/spirit/issues/434